# Unable to process binding "value: function() {return myVar }"

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js and am trying to get a `<select>` tag to populate with options from on of the view model's properties. I think I did everything right but it breaks. The console error is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function(){return myArray } at value (eval at parseBindingsString, :3:237)"

### My Code:

**js**

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myArray = ko.observableArray([
        { text: 'First Item', value: '1' },
        { text: 'Second Item', value: '2' }
    ]);
}
```

**cshtml**

```
<div style="flex-basis: 100%;">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: ThisArray">
        <li>
            <select data-bind="options: myArray, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Select item', value: degreeType"></select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I feel like I'm using the right syntax. Not sure why I'm getting this error. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I just added `self` in front of `myArray` (self.myArray) and now the error is gone. However, my array elements aren't in the dropdown. I don't think I should have to add the `self` so I'm not sure what's going on there either.

Comment: Using `vm` instead of `self` now gives me data in the dropdown. I'm adding to an existing legacy code. None of the other `selects` getting data from KO have this prefix so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I can see going on here.  The first is that in the example javascript provided there is no `ThisArray` to match the foreach binding on the `ul`.  Another issue is that there is no `degreeType` in the `MyViewModel`.

One problem I think you are having with knockout is recognising changes in context boundaries in the HTML. [Knockout Binding context documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)
Hopefully the following examples are able to help.

```js
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myArray = ko.observableArray([
        { text: 'First Item', value: '1'},
        { text: 'Second Item', value: '2' }
    ]);
    self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
}


var PageModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.ThisArray = ko.observableArray([new MyViewModel(), new MyViewModel(),]);
}

let model = new PageModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js"></script>
 <div style="flex-basis: 100%;"> <!-- PageModel context -->
    <ul data-bind="foreach: ThisArray"> <!-- PageModel context -->
        <li> <!-- MyViewModel context  -->
            <select data-bind="options: myArray, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Select item', value: selectedValue"></select>
        </li> <!-- MyViewModel context  -->
    </ul> <!-- PageModel context  -->
</div> <!-- PageModel context -->

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
```

if you need to reference a property on a parent context then you can use `$parent` or `$parents[0]`

```js
var MyViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
}


var PageModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.ThisArray = ko.observableArray([new MyViewModel(), new MyViewModel(), ]);

  self.myArray = ko.observableArray([
    { text: 'First Item', value: '1'},
    { text: 'Second Item', value: '2'}
  ]);
}

let model = new PageModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.min.js"></script>
<div style="flex-basis: 100%;">
  <!-- PageModel context -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach: ThisArray">
    <!-- PageModel context -->
    <li>
      <!-- MyViewModel context  -->
      <select data-bind="options: $parent.myArray, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Select item', value: selectedValue"></select>
    </li>
    <!-- MyViewModel context  -->
  </ul>
  <!-- PageModel context  -->
</div>
<!-- PageModel context -->

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
```